# R: Creating a new data.frame consisting of the mean of subsets of different length from another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Let's image to have a dataframe such as

```
df<-data.frame(Steps=1:10, Value=20:29)
> df
   Steps Value
1      1    20
2      2    21
3      3    22
4      4    23
5      5    24
6      6    25
7      7    26
8      8    27
9      9    28
10    10    29
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Taking different subsets of the dataframe based on different number of steps (so for example after 2 steps or after 5 steps, and so on...). The number of steps are decided arbitrary, so they could be 1,2 and 3 steps or 2,4,7 and 10 steps. The number of steps might cover or not the whole length of the data.frame(but if doing the whole length it is easier, is fine, I can filter after)
2. Calculate the mean of df$value
3. Create a new df including the number of steps and the mean of df$value for those number of steps

So, for example, I would like to have a df2 like this:

```
> df2<-data.frame(Steps=c(2,5,10), Value=c(20.5,22,24.5))
> df2
  Steps Value
1     2  20.5
2     5  22.0
3    10  24.5
```

I can only think of using a for cycle. Any better idea?

Comment: updated the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking random steps of random lengths.

```
set.seed(123)
random_steps <- sort(sample(df$Steps, sample(nrow(df), 1)))

df2 <- data.frame(steps = random_steps, 
                  Value = sapply(random_steps, function(x) mean(df$Value[df$Steps <= x])))
df2

#  steps Value
#1     2  20.5
#2     3  21.0
#3     6  22.5
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(Steps=1:10, Value=20:29)

tibble(Steps = c(2, 5, 10),
       Value = map_dbl(Steps,
               ~ df %>%
                 filter(Steps <= .x) %>%
                 pull(Value) %>%
                 mean()
               )
       )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Steps Value
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2  20.5
#> 2     5  22  
#> 3    10  24.5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr::cummean` to get the cumulative mean up to each step, then `dplyr::slice` to select the rows you want to see the cummean for

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(Steps = 1:10, Value = 20:29)

df %>%
  mutate(cummean = cummean(Value)) %>%
  slice(2, 5, 10) %>%
  select(Steps, cummean)
#>   Steps cummean
#> 1     2    20.5
#> 2     5    22.0
#> 3    10    24.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>